# monitor state of model node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, state-machine

I would like to monitor state of the model which is responsible for rendering different views for HR and the candidate. Depending on the job, when the candidate applies for it there are three possibilities at the moment (it will grow, and that's the reason I am asking the question), answer the questions, or just have a test assignment or have the test assignment and answer the questions. The HR depending on what stage the applicant is have a custom view, and applicant, depending on what stage they are should have their custom view. Therefore in the `JobApplication` model there two `columns`: `client_view | hr_view | requirements` in the `requirements` the steps are saved. For example `"assignment:questions"`, or `questions`.

```
     |     client_view     |  hr_view   | requirements |
     ----------------------------------------------------
       "active_questions"   "not_active"  "questions" 

     |     client_view     |  hr_view   | requirements |
     ----------------------------------------------------
       "active_assignment"   "active"     "assignment"
```

[image: States]

Changes should be made to the model every time client from the application makes a `PATCH` request. At the moment I came up with very bad scaleless   solution

```
'use strict';
class ApplicationState {
  constructor(requirements) {
    this._states = {
      questions: { client_view: 'active_questions', hr_view: 'not_active' },
      assignment: { client_view: 'active_assignment', hr_view: 'active' },
      done: { client_view: 'not_active', hr_view: 'active' }
    };

    this.requirements = requirements;
    this.current = requirements.length === 1 ? this._states[requirements[0]] :  this._states.questions;
  }

  next () {
    if (this.current === this._states.questions && this.requirements.indexOf('assignment') !== -1) {
      this.current = this._states.assignment;
    } else {
      this.current = this._states.done;
    }
  }
}
module.exports = ApplicationState;
```

And in my model I invoke it

```
var applicationState = new ApplicationState(applicationModel.requirements)
applicationModel.setStates(applicationState.next())
```